# set value with Javascript on a field for users that do not have proper field level security privilages

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a client who would like have the value of a boolean field (lets call this fieldA) changed when the user changes the value of a 2nd boolean field (let call this fieldB).  fieldA has field level security enabled.

I have created JavaScript that does this and it works just fine when the user has the proper field level security privilages on fieldA.  When they don't have the proper privilages it does not seem to work?

Is it posible to have JavaScript change the value of fieldA for users **without** field level privilages on fieldA?  If not, is there a trick that can be done to override the FLS temporaraly in JS?

Thank you

Comment: I guess first comment would be why use FLS if you we going to ignore it? Is it really needed? Culd you use JS to enable/disable the field instead as required?

Comment: I think the client wants to know that users without the FLS can never change fieldA (from SSIS packages, from edit multiple, on the from, etc).  I think They just want my JavaScript to be the one case that overrides FLS.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason to mandate JavaScript? I'd suggest that a pre-update plugin would circumvent the FLS issue.

Comment: I think I will need to proceed with some sort of combination Javascript to enable and disable and update fieldA as needed, and write a preupdate plugin, as suggested, to remove fieldA from the entity attribute collection, and then lose the FLS.  Unless someone has a better idea.  Thanks!